# Given two arrays, how can one determine the the intersection?

Tags: algorithms, data-analysis, data-mining

I have two datasets (A & B). They each have 1000 numbers.

99% of the time: A < x <= B

However, 1% of the time B < x < A.

How can I solve for `x`, where `x` has the highest probability of separating the two groups.

Obviously Max(A) and Min(B) are misleading because there are occasional anomalies (<2%). Can you help me determine the optimum "x" with the highest probability on both sides?

```
Sample Dataset

A 1
A 1
A 1
A 2
B 2 <--anomoly
A 3
A 3
A 3
A 4
A 5 <--anomoly
B 5 <--division, or `x`
B 5
B 5
B 5
A 6 <--anomoly
B 7
B 8
B 8
B 8
B 9
B 9
B 10
B 10
```

Comment: It seems you want to minimize the number of $B$s below $x$ plus the number of $A$s above $x$?

Comment: Or perhaps, you want to minimize the maximum of the number of $B$s below $x$ and the number of $A$s above $x$?

Comment: Correct. What do you recommend?

Comment: Looks like your dataset is sorted. Why not take the boundary as the point which the smallest 99% of A is less, i.e. 990 instances of A is less than x?

Comment: Or given whatever metric you want to minimize, you can do a single pass through your sorted data (2000 points) and minimize over all possible cutoffs (2000 potential locations). You can condense your data and just use the frequency histogram, too.

Comment: @Evan, is it possible without iterating through the data points? What would a frequency histogram accomplish? Do you mean group bunches of the sorted data (maybe in 100s, then 10s), and then show frequency until it drops below a threshold?

Comment: @Ryan  Hmm.. nevermind about the frequency histogram. Actually the title of this problem reminded me of an intersection of two (unsorted) sets problem in linear time which was accomplished by placing the elements of A in a hash table and then for each element of B, checking if it already exists in the hash table. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4642172/computing-set-intersection-in-linear-time  But this also requires a pass-through on the data. Also it doesn't seem to address this problem. What about peterwhy's earlier suggestion of taking 99%-ile?

Comment: @peterwhy, this got me close. Here's what I did with my actual dataset... took the questionably overlapping 2% off of both groups, then averaged the remaining Max(A) and Min(B). Unfortunately this trended a few points lower than a human, but might be acceptable.

Comment: Hum... can you say what is already computed? Isn't this procedure also doing a loop through the data?

Comment: @Evan, fair enough. I was hoping there was a more math route to the answer but I'm pretty darn close now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the sample you have given, sort the datasets in ascending order. If there are both A's and B's for any same number, sort all those A's before those B's.

Now, we have a sequence of 1000 A's and 1000 B's mixed together. Initialise an error counter $e=1000$.

Sequentially scan the sequence. If an A is encountered, decrease $e$ by 1. If a B is encountered instead, increase $e$ by 1.

Also, store the split point that minimises $e$ throughout the scan. The corresponding number value, which equals to the average of the number values before and after the split, will be the boundary that minimises number of mis-classification.

Comment: I appreciate it. It sounds like this requires one to loop through the options to identify the optimum answer. Is there not a way to calculate the optimum without the loop?

Comment: I ran this through a real dataset quickly in excel and was within row of what a human would find. Well done.